# How to prevent upper case in page header?

Tags: math-mode, header-footer, capitalization

I just came across this small problem which I can't seem to fix. I have a section which looks like this:

```
\section{Properties of $C_q$}
```

The problem is that the header of the page uses upper case and so it displays this section title as if I had written

```
\section{Properties of $C_Q$}
```

How can I make sure the q is always lower case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could define a macro for this expression:

```
\newcommand{\Cq}{C_q}
```

and protect it when you use it in such headings:

```
\section{Properties of $\protect\Cq$}
```

`\protect` prevents early expansion of the macro, this way also becoming uppercase is prevented. You may use this macro later in your math expression as well, of course, that's why I did not start math mode inside the macro.

Btw. I would not use all caps headers. In case of fancyhdr, for example, uppercasing can be disabled by `\nouppercase`, such as

```
\rhead{\nouppercase\leftmark}
```