# Stop memoir from making mathmode section names uppercase in header

Tags: math-mode, header-footer, memoir, capitalization

I'm typesetting my thesis with `memoir` and in general I'm happy with the result.  However, some of my section headers have math mode text like `\section{The $\phi_{ij}$ matrix}` which `memoir` comically turns into `$\phi_{IJ}$` in the header.  I'm new to memoir so I don't really know my way around.

Is there a way to tell it to leave mathmode in lower case when it prints the header?

I'm using XeLaTeX with TeX live downloaded yesterday via tlmgr. Full example, including possibly interfering packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a chapter}

\section{The $\phi_{ij}$ Matrix}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\section{Density - $\omega^j_c$}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks:
[image: Example of rendering]

Comment: Is that a sufficient level of detail?

Comment: Using `\section{Density - \lowercase{$\omega^j_c$}}` suppresses the capitalization.

Comment: Ok, I guess that will work.  But is there a way to tell `memoir` to wrap all mathmode lines in headers with `\lowercase`?

Comment: Just discovered an almost identical question with a different solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40421/how-to-prevent-upper-case-in-page-header

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want uppercase headings, it's sufficient to say

```
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
```

that will change `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase` into "math-aware" commands.

### Aside

I should mention a few things about your preamble.

- `hyperref` should be loaded last;
- It's a bit strange to load both `longtable` and `supertabular`
- `memoir` has its own way to set the line spacing and saying only `\linespread{1.5}` is quite defective in many situations
- When you have math in a section title, consider using `\texorpdfstring`: for instance

  ```
  \section{Density --- \texorpdfstring{$\omega^j_c$}{omega j c}}
  ```

  that avoids many messages by `hyperref`

Answer (score 5):

actually, this *does* appear to be standard behavior of `memoir`.  here are a few definitions from `memoir.cls`:

```
\newcommand*{\nouppercaseheads}{\let\memUChead\relax}
\newcommand*{\uppercaseheads}{\let\memUChead\MakeUppercase}
\uppercaseheads
```

try adding `\nouppercaseheads` in your preamble.

really, the `\MakeUppercase` should be changed to something "math-aware" like the `\uppercasenonmath` defined in the ams document classes.  (i've written to the maintainer of `memoir.cls` to suggest it.)

Comment: How would I combine the `\uppercasenonmath` with `memoir`?  It could be that lower case headers are better in general but I'd like to know how to tell just the math to be left alone.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz, sorry for the lack of clarity.  The title and tags pointed to header but I was sloppy on the question.

Comment: @mmdanziger: Thanks for clarifying! I removed my comments, perhaps to the same, so the question stands clear, for future readers. I'll remove this mine too :-)

Comment: I've added it to my todo list, I'm not going to `fix` it, but rather provide some features like the ones `ams` use. I personally do not like using uppercase headings, (1) takes up to much space, (2) in these web days, uppercasing equal shouting ...