# Preventing \MakeUppercase from affecting mathematics

Tags: math-mode, capitalization

Is there a way to prevent `\MakeUppercase` from affecting in-text equations? In this example, `abc` should change to `ABC`, but `n` should be left as it is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{abc $n$}
\end{document}
```

The following works for individual characters, but I would like something more general.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcount\mycount
\mycount\mathcode`n
\MakeUppercase{abc $\mathchar\mycount$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try the `textcase` package, AFAIK it has a `\MakeUppercaseText` macro

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option. This problem arises from a journal document class applying `\MakeUppercase` to section headings. I need to prevent the existing command from affecting mathematics.

Comment: So you want to modify `\MakeUppercase` then?

Comment: @Werner --- I thought there might be some way to prevent `\MakeUppercase` from changing mathematics, similar to the use of braces to prevent `BIBTeX` from changing the case of letters. Failing that, your suggestion of `\let\MakeUppercas\MakeTextUppercase` looks like a good alternative.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `textcase` package was already mentioned. But if you are forced to stay with an unchanged `\MakeUppercase`for some reason then you still have the poor man's choice of "hiding" the math:

```
\newcommand\hidemath{$n$}
\MakeUppercase{abc \protect\hidemath}
```

The `\protect` is needed as `\MakeUppercase` in LaTeX is essentially an `\edef` that only stops expanding at `\protect`.

Or the alternative with eTeX which has protection at the macro definition level:

```
\protected\def\hiddenmath{$n$}
\MakeUppercase{abc \hiddenmath}
```

Comment: I think the 'poor man's' choice is the best option here. I need this for a journal article, and the publishers may view redefining `\MakeUppercase` as hacking their class file.

Answer (score 15):

[`textcase`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcase) provides `\MakeTextUppercase`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcase}% http://ctan.org/pkg/textcase
\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{abc $n$} \par
\MakeTextUppercase{abc $n$}
\end{document}
```

For easy modification across the entire document, I suggest issuing

```
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}% http://ctan.org/pkg/textcase
```

which "overloads" both `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase` with `\MakeTextUppercase` and `\MakeTextLowercase`, respectively. Similar to

```
\let\MakeUppercase\MakeTextUppercase
\let\MakeLowercase\MakeTextLowercase
```

Apparently the AMS document classes also provide this functionality - a math-aware `\MakeUppercase` using `\uppercasenonmath`. See @barbarabeeton's answer to [Stop memoir from making mathmode section names uppercase in header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42188/5764).