# Lower case in chapter header

Tags: header-footer

I am writing a document using the `book` class. The problem is, that I want the headers to be in lowercase letters. How to force them to be lower case?

A sample code is

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one $e^--p^+$}
        \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

and the ouptut looks like that

[image]

Comment: Does this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46525/preventing-makeuppercase-from-affecting-mathematics

Comment: Do you want to keep the case of the entire heading? So your header reads `Chapter 1. Chapter one $e^--p^+$` and not `CHAPTER 1. CHAPTER ONE $E^--P^+$`? Or just `CHAPTER 1. CHAPTER ONE $e^--p^+$`?

Comment: If you're not using *any* form of automatic uppercase in your document, add `\let\MakeUppercase\relax` to your document preamble.

Comment: the ams document classes define a routine `\uppercasenonmath` that was written for this purpose.  you might be able to extract it (and some other required definitions) from `amsbook.cls`.  the macro documentation is in `amsclass.dtx`, which can be found on ctan in the `macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/` area; a somewhat more "readable" version (a pdf file generated from the `.dtx`) can be had with `texdoc amsclass' on a tex live installation (if the documentation has been installed), or from ctan in the `doc` subdirectory of the cited area.

Comment: @Werner: I believe that your suggestion is very nice! It suits me best! Do you mind, answering the question, in order to accept your answer? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not using *any* form of automatic capitalization in your document, add

```
\let\MakeUppercase\relax
```

to your document preamble. This makes `\MakeUppercase` (used in the default [`book` document class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) to make the capitalize the headers) turn into a no-op.

[image]

However, other elements of your document might still use this without you knowing it. It's better to define these headers in an abstract and manageable way through page styles. Here's one using [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps):

```
\usepackage{titleps}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps
\makeatletter
\newpagestyle{main}{% Define page style main
  \sethead%
    [\slshape\thesection.\ \sectiontitle][][]% [<even-left>][<even-centre>][<even-right>]
    {}{}{\slshape\@chapapp~\thechapter.\ \chaptertitle}% {<odd-left>}{<odd-centre>}{<odd-right>}
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}% {<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}
}
\pagestyle{main}% Use page style main
```

Some more details are available from the [`titleps` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) or from [`titleps` for `fan­cy­hdr` users](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/titleps_fancyhdr.html).

Comment: I'd not recommend it.

Comment: @egreg: Why not?

Comment: @Thanos Because `\MakeUppercase` might be used implicitly somewhere else.

Comment: @egreg: I see. So what would be the best option?

Comment: @Thanos If you want to keep the uppercasing except for math, the question which yours is proposed as a duplicate of has the answer; otherwise, use `fancyhdr` to remove it with `\nouppercase`.

Comment: @egreg: I would like to keep lower case in the chapter's header, not only in math.

Comment: @Thanos Please, edit the question in order to make this clear, so that it won't be a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @egreg: It is now edited! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 10):

Setting the headers with `fancyhdr` in order to avoid automatic uppercasing is easy; add font choice commands such as `\itshape` before `\nouppercase`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

% This is just for the example
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\newcommand\achap{
  \chapter{Title with math $a+b=c$}
  \section{Abc}\kant\section{Bcd}\kant\section{Cde}\kant}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\achap\achap\achap\achap
\achap\achap\achap\achap
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Related to your edit you can redefine the default definition of `\chaptermark`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\chaptermark#1{\markright{
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne\if@mainmatter
        \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi\fi #1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one $e^--p^+$}
        \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

---

A second approach would be the usage of the package `fancyhdr` as suggest in the comment:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one $e^--p^+$}
        \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```