# Preserving part of Chapter text "as is", from becoming uppercase as per titlesec definition?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, capitalization

Having this MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{This should be all Uppercase.  "This text should remain as it is"}
\end{document}
```

Which command could one use to have the text `"This text should remain as it is"` *not* affected by the titlesec uppercase definition (see image)?

[image]

Edit: Fixed `\titleformat`'s arguments, as per Gonzalo Medina's remark (see below).

Comment: Related: [Preventing `\MakeUppercase` from affecting mathematics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46525/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option would be to load the [`textcase`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcase) package and use `\MakeTextUppercase` instead of `\MakeUppercase` for the title formatting (this, in any case, is a good idea to prevent issues with possible `\label`s  and math expressions inside titles); now you can use `\NoCaseChange` to preserve the case of the desired text:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcase}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\filcenter\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{This should be all Uppercase. \NoCaseChange{This text should remain as it is}}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### Remark

Your current definition of `\titleformat` is faulty; the fourth mandatory argument cannot be empty, so I'd suggest you to change it to something like

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
```

(notice that no provision was made regarding the counters so `\chapter` will produce unnumbered chapters)

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for, a command like `\NoCaseChange`. Thanks.

Comment: May I know what the line `\DeclareRobustCommand{\shouldremain}{}` does? Your answer works even without it. Would you know why using the normal (no star) version, `\chapter{This should be all Uppercase. \NoCaseChange{"This text should remain as it is"}}`, seems to throw an error? `Chapter 1.
./macro.tex:18: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>`

Comment: @gsl I'm on my mobile now, so writing code is painful. Later I'll provide a proper answer. For now, the line you mentioned is superfluous, and can be safely deleted. The error is due to the fact that your \titleformat definition is wrong (the fourth argument cannot be empty). As I said, later I'll write a proper answer.

Comment: @gsl I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the ad-hoc usage you can define a robust command that contains the fixed-text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\centering {\MakeUppercase {#1}}} {} {} {} %

\begin{document}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\shouldremain}{This text should remain as it is}
\chapter*{This should be all Uppercase. \shouldremain}

\end{document}
```

If you're using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), you can also use

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
%...
\chapter*{This should be all Uppercase. \MakeSentenceCase{This text should remain as it is}}
```

Comment: Thank you, also for letting me know about `\MakeSentenceCase`. Thanks!