# Improper first paragraph indentation after grouped sections

Tags: sectioning, indentation, paragraphs, grouping, parindent

I have a KOMA-based document where section footnotes and text footnotes are formatted differently:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \protected\def\hidefootnoteSec{\MakeUppercase{Section footnote.}} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46532)
    \begingroup%
    \deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{{\Large\thefootnotemark}\hspace*{.5em}}
    \section[A section]{A section{\protect\NoHyper\protect\footnote[1]{\hidefootnoteSec}\protect\endNoHyper}}
    \endgroup%

    Test paragraph: should not be indented, but~due to~\verb|group| enclosing section it is.

    Second test paragraph~\footnote{text footnote.}:~should be indented.
\end{document}
```

In general, first paragraph of a section in such document is not indented, but in this case, the `\begingroup`…`\endgroup` declaration causes LaTeX to fail on detecting that there is `section` declared just above the first paragraph. Simply removing the group would make the formatting affect the next footnotes too.

Of course, it is possible to manually force `\noindent` in the first paragraph. Yet here I am looking for a more automated solution, so that in a bigger document one does not need to always remember about such additions when adding/removing new footnotes or changing the global indentation.

[image: Documents]

Is it possible to automatically detect first paragraph after such footnoted–grouped sections for the purpose of (not) indenting it?

Comment: don't put a group and footnote redefinition in the document, just redefine footnotes within the group already used for setting up the heading fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch the footnote redefinition into `\sectionlinesformat` (KOMA-Script command provided by `scrartcl`):

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\sectionlinesformat}
  {\ifstr{#1}{section}{\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{{\Large\thefootnotemark}\hspace*{.5em}}}{}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\protected\def\hidefootnoteSec{\MakeUppercase{Section footnote.}} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46532)
\section[A section]{A section{\protect\NoHyper\protect\footnote[1]{\hidefootnoteSec}\protect\endNoHyper}}

Test paragraph: should not be indented, but~due to~\verb|group| enclosing section it is.

Second test paragraph~\footnote{text footnote.}:~should be indented.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or without the `\hidefootnoteSec`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\sectionlinesformat}
  {\ifstr{#1}{section}{\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{{\Large\thefootnotemark}\hspace*{.5em}}}{}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section[A section]{A section{\NoHyper\footnote[1]{\MakeUppercase{Section footnote.}}\endNoHyper}}

Test paragraph: should not be indented, but~due to~\verb|group| enclosing section it is.

Second test paragraph~\footnote{text footnote.}:~should be indented.
\end{document}
```

---

With the prerelease of KOMA-Script version 3.27 (available [here](https://komascript.de/node/1801)) you can also use `\AddtoDoHook`

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2019/07/23]% needs at least prerelease 3.27.3175
\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\newcommand\sectionfootnote[1]{\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{{\Large\thefootnotemark}\hspace*{.5em}}}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/section}{\sectionfootnote}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section[A section]{A section{\NoHyper\footnote[1]{\MakeUppercase{Section footnote.}}\endNoHyper}}

Test paragraph: should not be indented, but~due to~\verb|group| enclosing section it is.

Second test paragraph~\footnote{text footnote.}:~should be indented.
\end{document}
```

or `\AddtoOneTimeDoHook`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2019/07/23]% needs at least prerelease 3.27.3175
\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\newcommand*\sectionfootnote[1]{\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{{\Large\thefootnotemark}\hspace*{.5em}}}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/begingroup/section}{\sectionfootnote}% only for the next \section
\section[A section]{A section{\NoHyper\footnote[1]{\MakeUppercase{Section footnote.}}\endNoHyper}}

Test paragraph: should not be indented, but~due to~\verb|group| enclosing section it is.

Second test paragraph~\footnote{text footnote.}:~should be indented.
\end{document}
```