# Chemical formula in fancyhdr environment

Tags: fancyhdr, chemistry

I am using the `fancyhdr` package to create nice headers for my thesis. I'm running into problems with a chemical formula that appears as a section name.

The chemical formula is capitalized when displayed in the header:
[image]

However, I'd like to have it formatted like this:
[image]

*How can I make LaTeX to format the header correctly for this chemical formula without changing the uppercase conversion for other chapter / section names?*

A minimal example of the code I used is:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}

% Load all packages
%\input{preamble.tex}
\newcommand{\bisb}{Bi$_{1-x}$Sb$_{x}\,$}
\usepackage{blindtext} % For testing purposes

% Define the headers here
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\thepage}\quad\quad\quad \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark\quad\quad\quad \textbf{\thepage}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{\bisb}
\blindtext[20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, `\nouppercase{\leftmark}` and `\nouppercase{\rightmark}`. This does not influence the chemical formula, but makes all header *not* use UPPERCASE.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue you're reporting, using just the information you've provided so far. (I do get an error message about an option clash for the `textcomp` package, apparently related to the instruction `\DeclareRobustCommand{\sustyle}...`.) Please post a fully compilable example that generates the issue you're looking to fix.

Comment: Hi Johannes, thanks for the answer. However, I'd like to have the other sections to appear in uppercase, so that does not fix the problem completely.

Comment: Hi Mico, I have just updated the question with a new code snippet that I just ran. I hope this provides enough information.

Comment: You should be using a proper package for chemistry support such as `chemformula` and `chemmacros` (my favourite) or `mhchem` (which is also good).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40424/117534 ?

Answer (score 0):

Troy's answer has provided the right code to get what I want. By using

```
\section{\protect\bisb}
```

LaTeX no longer makes the formula appear in uppercase.

Thanks!